# How to make jQuery loading screen view at least 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animated-gif

I just created my own loading screen with this code:

```
HTML CODE: <div class="loader"></div>

CSS CODE: .loader {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 9999;
            background: url(../Images/page-loader.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);}

jQuery CODE: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



AND
             $(window).load(function() {
             $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");})
```

Each time the page loads, the loading screen only displays for a fraction of a second. Im trying to display the loading screen at least 3 seconds. What jQuery code should I add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setInterval`

```
$(window).load(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow")
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: This will actually delay the fadeOut by more than 3 seconds. This will wait until the whole page loads (which is a variable non zero amount) and THEN wait 3 seconds, which is technically not what the OP requested.

Comment: I think the solution is sufficient enough for the requirement. and OP already replied above.

Answer (score 1):

To delay the fadeOut action you can use the `delay()` function in jQuery
https://api.jquery.com/delay/

This will delay your fadeout by 3s (3000ms).

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".loader").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the site